# Optimization with implicit constraints

Tags: optimization

I want to minimize the following objective function:

$\min_{w,v} f(w,v) + g(w,a^*) \qquad (*)$

where

$a^* = \arg\min_a h(w,a) $.

If I can have an analytical solution for $a^*$ with respect to $w$, then I can put it back to $(*)$. But what if I don't have an analytical solution?

Thank you!

Comment: Bilevel Optimization http://luthuli.cs.uiuc.edu/~daf/courses/Optimization/BilevelSubmodularMaterial/Bilevel.pdf .Include the KKT optimality conditions for $a^*$ as constraints added to the problem (*) and solve the (combined) problem numerically. These problems can be very tough to solve.

Comment: Hi Mark, I think this is the solution I am looking for. Thanks very much!